# query that worked in Laravel 5.2 give me error in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

This query works in 5.2:

```
    $galleries = Gallery::with(array(
            'images' => function ($query) {
                $query->orderBy('order', 'asc');
            }
        ))
        ->with('votes')
        ->leftJoin('votes', 'votes.votable_id', '=', 'gallery.id')
        ->selectRaw(
            'gallery.*, count(case votes.status when "upvote" then 1 else null end) - count(case votes.status when "downvote" then 1 else null end) as points'
        )
        ->where('votes.votable_type','App\Gallery')
        ->groupBy('gallery.id')
        ->orderBy('points', 'desc')
        ->published()->orderBy('gallery.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(30);
```

I am trying to select all galleries that have votes, when I run this in 5.3 I get this

```
 1/2 PDOException in Connection.php line 333: SQLSTATE[42000]: 
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'images.gallery.title' isn't in GROUP BY 

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'images.gallery.title' isn't in 
GROUP BY (SQL: select gallery.*, count(case votes.status when "upvote" then 1 else null end) - count(case votes.status when "downvote" then 1 else null end) 
as points from `gallery` left join `votes` on `votes`.`votable_id` = `gallery`.`id`
where `votes`.`votable_type` = App\Gallery and `published` = 1 group by `gallery`.`id` 
order by `points` desc, `gallery`.`created_at` desc limit 30 offset 0)
```

Comment: have you tried adding the mission `gallery.title` to the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: yes I tried that, then it tells me to add all the columns in my gallery table, so I end up with this:

            ->groupBy('gallery.id', 'gallery.title', 'gallery.hash', 'gallery.user_id', 'gallery.published', 'gallery.views' , 'gallery.created_at', 'gallery.updated_at') but that doesnt look right to me. Do you think its right?

Comment: The documentation mentions in the upgrade guide to 5.3 that the `join`method has been rewritten. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

Answer (score 12):

Go to your config/database.php folder. In mysql configuration array, change `strict => true` to `strict => false`, and everything will work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation your join query should like this 
Reference -:https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

```
 $galleries = Gallery::with(array(
        'images' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('order', 'asc');
        }
    ))
    ->with('votes')
    ->leftJoin('votes',function($query){
                 $query->on('votes','gallery')->where('votes', 'votes.votable_id', '=', 'gallery.id')->where('votes.votable_type','App\Gallery');   })->selectRaw(
        'gallery.*, count(case votes.status when "upvote" then 1 else null end) - count(case votes.status when "downvote" then 1 else null end) as points'
    )
    ->groupBy('gallery.id')
    ->orderBy('points', 'desc')
    ->published()->orderBy('gallery.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(30);
```

Comment: Hi Hamza, running that I get this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'gallery.id `votes` = ? where `votes`.`votable_type` = ? and `published` = ? grou' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `gallery` left join `votes` on `votes` = `gallery` gallery.id `votes` = votes.votable_id where `votes`.`votable_type` = App\Gallery and `published` = 1 group by `gallery`.`id`) any ideas what it's complaning about?

Comment: I run toSql() on the query and this is sql that it produces: "select gallery.*, count(case votes.status when "upvote" then 1 else null end) - count(case votes.status when "downvote" then 1 else null end) as points from `gallery` left join `votes` on `votes` = `gallery` gallery.id `votes` = ? where `votes`.`votable_type` = ? and `published` = ? group by `gallery`.`id` order by `points` desc, `gallery`.`created_at` desc"

Comment: I have updated the answer try that and see if get your desired output or not

Comment: this is the right way to do it  ->leftJoin('votes',function($query){
                         $query->on('votes.votable_id','gallery.id'); it produces the same query as in 5.2 however I still get the 'images.gallery.title' isn't in GROUP BY. I reported this read more here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997#issuecomment-242046416 and give input if you got any ideas left, thanks :)

Comment: the issue is solved, laravel 5.3 has 'strict' => true, in config/database.php which turns on ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY when querying which causes the error

Comment: @Maxlight Thanks for sharing the info