# Laravel Error when I fetch data from a view table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

**Hi** , 
**i create a table as view from my phpMyAdmin
and everything work fine .**

**the problem now is when i connect to the view from   laravel**

**I got**

[image]

My database name "organization" 
and my view code is

```
select a.id, a.title,a.budget,a.image ,c.name as cname, t.name as Types , COUNT(b.id) as Donator, sum(b.amount) as finishAt
from cases a
  left join donations b
on b.case_id = a.id
left join category c on c.id = a.category_id
LEFT JOIN type t on t.id=c.type_id
group by a.id
```

**everything fine from my phpMyAdmin and there is no error there :**

[image]

My laravel code

```
    $result = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `caseview` ');
```

Any one have an idea please ?

Comment: Take a look at `http://programmingarehard.com/2013/11/10/eloquent_and_views.html/` this might help you to get data from views.

Comment: Create Migration for your MySQL View with Model class. Instead of creating from mysql

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120862/query-that-worked-in-laravel-5-2-give-me-error-in-laravel-5-3#answer-39403205

Comment: @RaghavendraN thank you so so much man :) this solved the problem , I always do the same but this time on laravel 5.3 i dont know why it was like that . thank you again

Comment: if you can post your answer  to chose it as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RaghavendraN comment :

You have to Go to your `config/database.php` folder. In mysql configuration array, change `strict => true` to `strict => false`,